# Proof of $a = d(\frac12v^2)/dx$

Tags: kinematics, derivatives

So I completely understand how $a = v(dv/dx)$. But how does differentiating $\frac12 v^2$ with respect to $x$ get you to $v(dv/dx)$. Can someone put all steps in please?

Why can you say $d(\frac12 v^2)/dx = \frac12  \times 2v \times dv/dx$ (where does $2v$ and $dv/dx$ come from? Is it actually written properly as $\frac12 d(v^2)/dx$? Then I'm assuming you take the differential out i.e. $2v$ to get the $2v$?

Comment: This question should be on mathSE,  VTC on that basis.

Comment: Its part of my mechanics course so I assumed newtonian mechanics would be best.

Comment: I believe the closest thing we have to a policy on this is [this meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/should-pure-math-questions-be-on-topic), which says that that math in the context of physics is on topic here. This question seems to meet that description.

Comment: Fully accepted, but this part is pure mathSE  and you have a better chance of an answer, and more examples there. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Ok, in the light of what David has said, I think you should say what section of mechanics you are doing, that is, what physics lead you to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know that

$$a=v \frac{dv}{dx},$$

you can prove it like this:

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{dv^2}{dx}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{dv^2}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{2v}{2} \frac{dv}{dx}=v\frac{dv}{dx}=a.$$

Comment: Yes, great! I will think of the proof like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a mechanics course you should already have at least Calculus I under your belt. This is just a basic derivative,

$\frac{d}{dx}( x^2 ) = 2x $.

Now if you are taking the derivative of something that depends on $x$, like $v=v(x)$ in your case,

$\frac{d}{dx} ( f(x)^2 ) = 2f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}$,

from the chain rule.

Comment: Yes I get this. Didn't think of it like it was v(x). Sorry i am 17 so haven't learnt everything on calculus yet.

Comment: No need to be sorry, you have to start somewhere! Eventually connections like this will become clear to you with practice.  The power of math is in generalization like this. You can also see that $dv/dt = (dv/dx)(dx/dt)$ from the chain rule, and $dx/dt=v$ so $a=(dv/dt)=v(dv/dx)$.